# Firebase login Facebook / Google - UID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im almost finishing a job and got a huge problem, I did the login/register using firebase and to call some functions I used in almost the hole project the uid like firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {if(user.uid) do something... the problem is, Im adding the login with Google/Facebook and it doesn't have a uid of the firebase (if Im doing right), there is something to do like when loging with some social midia the firebase register some uid to that user, this is what Im doing:

```
   case this.GOOGLE:
              var providerr = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
              var result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(providerr);
              var user = result.user.providerData;
                if(user[0].uid){
                  let nome = user[0].displayName;
                  let nome1 = nome.substr(0,nome.indexOf(' '));
                  let nome2 = nome.substr(nome.indexOf(' ')+1);
                  let usuario = { nome: "",
                              sobrenome:"",
                              email:user[0].email,
                              telefone:"",
                              picture:"" 
                            }

                  usuario.nome = nome1?nome1:"";
                  usuario.sobrenome = nome2?nome2:"";
                  usuario.picture = user[0].photoURL?user[0].photoURL:"";
                  usuario.telefone =   user[0].phoneNumber?user[0].phoneNumber:"";
                  firebaseDatabase.ref().child('/profile/' + user[0].uid )
                  .update(usuario);
                  return 1;
                }
                else return -1;
                 break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase only stores a list of email+password users. It does not store any data for the users that are signed with social providers (Facebook, Google).